# Run javascript when foreign page loads to manipulate it in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to tweak some pages I often visit with javascript + jquery. For example I want to hide one block and enlarge the other on the page. I need to store the script and have it automatically run each time I visit specified address.

Is there any method/extension in firefox that enables such javascript execution?

Comment: Firefox Extensions, Userscripts or simple bookmarklets. Google away

Comment: The Stylish extension lets you write your own stylesheet for any URL: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try very popular greasemonkey extension: 
[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)